# Assign the same value to different models, they work together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm sorry if there is an inappropriate expression because it is Google translation

I want to know a solution or workaround

I am trying to achieve the following in nuxt + vue + vuetfy environment

・Get user information using API and display it on the screen

・When you press the edit button, a dialog is displayed and user information is edited

・However, if you change the value on the edit screen, the display on the back also changes together.

```
<v-text-field label="name" readonly :value="userDetail.name"/>

<v-dialog v-model="dialog">
  <v-text-field label="name" v-model="userEdit.name"/>
</v-dialog>
```

```
async getUser () {
this.userDetail = API RESPONSE
this.userEdit = API RESPONSE
}
```

I was able to avoid it by assigning a value with another method, but it is not good

```
async getUser () {
this.userDetail = API RESPONSE
}
async getUser2 () {
this.userEdit = API RESPONSE
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Welcome to the best place in the world <3. the issue to your question is not clear. One point, v-model is two ways binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) here: `:value="userDetail.name"`. It's purpose is to update the DOM whenever the value of the variable changes.

You'll have to create a new property in `data` to save the old name that you want to display in the text field.

For example:

```
data() {
  return {
    oldName: ''
    ...
  }
}
```

```
async getUser () {
  this.userDetail = API RESPONSE
  this.oldName = this.userDetail.name
}
```

Change `:value="userDetail.name"` to `:value="oldName"`.

Comment: Thank you for answering
I forgot to mention it
There are other elements besides the "name" and I want to copy them all

```
  this.oldOther = this.userDetail.other

```
Is this the only way?

Comment: @reno You could save a clone of the entire object and use that instead. For example, use `oldUserDetail` and clone `userDetail` like `this.oldUserDetail = Object.assign({}, this.userDetail);`.

Comment: @reno it's a pleasure. You [mark an answer as "accepted"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it answered your question. :)